# Select all from another table in select query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, join

I have two tables:

**reviews**

- company_id (column)

**employees**

- company_id (column)
- email (column)

i have many reviews and many employees.

I have a select like this:

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user_id = :user_id";
```

**My question:** In the same select query, how can i select all (multiple) the employees's email using the company id from the reviews table?

Comment: You have not specified user_id column in your table specification. Please provide list of all the columns. And it would be better if you can provide sample data of both the table and your expected output as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the two tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM reviews
JOIN employees ON reviews.company_id = reviews.company_id
WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

`SELECT *` here will return all the columns of both the `reviews` and `employees` tables.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want using company_id from reviews table when employees table already has it. Anyway You can join 2 table together to resolve your issue. Like this:

```
SELECT email 
FROM employees e JOIN reviews r ON e.company_id = r.company_id 
WHERE r.company_id = :company_ud
```

Comment: I need to get that specific review and get the company associated with that review and all the emails associated with that company. Also I have multiple employees under that business, I am getting duplicate content...